# ERR_NETWORK_IO_SUSPENDED causing infinite requests

Tags: javascript, deployment

I have the following code which aims to automatically synchronize everything with a server.

This function is called once upon opening the website (logged in) or once the user logs in:

```
static async sync(): Promise<void> {
    while (this.active) {
        try {
            await SomeClass.sync()
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            this.active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: `SomeClass.sync()` is a different method! it's not recursive

`SomeClass.sync()` takes up to 30s to respond but it can respond immediately when a change occurs on the server; in that case it responds quicker and I make the next `SomeClass.sync()` call as soon as possible.

This works fine until the browser tab is inactive for too long or the PC goes to sleep mode. Because after opening the tab again I saw that thousands of sync requests were made and the followed error is seen in the command line (thousands of times) but the catch block is never entered.

> GET https://matrix-client.matrix.org/_matrix/client/v3/sync?filter=6&full_state=false&set_presence=online&timeout=30000&since=s4618108627_757284974_5471239_2578824090_2744102759_5162233_1222064987_9519760537_0_225843 net::ERR_NETWORK_IO_SUSPENDED

The main issue is that after opening the browser tab the calls resume correctly but everything is kind of laggy because tens of thousand of calls were made in that time (every 1-2ms).

I tried catching and logging the error in different ways but it was never caught. I also tried throwing an Error if await `someClass.sync()` doesn't resolve within X seconds but this didn't work either.

Comment: perhaps `SomeClass.sync()` doesn't *reject* when it needs to - it does return a Promise, right?

Comment: At the lowest level I have an Axios class which catches an error and rejects the Promise. However, this is a promise <AxiosReponse> and somewhere in the call hierarchy it changes to void. Do I need to explicitly reject it again in that case?

Comment: `and somewhere in the call hierarchy it changes to void` the what now?

Comment: The "lowest" level classes return Promises of AxiosResonse objects but one class uses that response and thus only returns a void promise. I explicitly catched and rejected the promise in that class and it seems to have finally resolved the issue